# HTTP CONNECT requests in Apache web server log

Tags: apache, http, security, proxy, mod-proxy

I have an Apache webserver which serves the domain **[www.mypersonaldomain.com](http://www.mypersonaldomain.com)** and I found these entries (and more like these) in access log.

```
88.218.227.227 - - [28/May/2021:08:56:29 +0000] "CONNECT minecraft.moin.games.:30003 HTTP/1.1" 302 213
88.218.227.227 - - [28/May/2021:08:57:03 +0000] "CONNECT minecraft.moin.games.:30003 HTTP/1.1" 302 213
88.218.227.227 - - [28/May/2021:08:58:19 +0000] "CONNECT minecraft.moin.games.:30003 HTTP/1.1" 302 213
34.91.147.149 - - [28/May/2021:10:34:44 +0000] "CONNECT play.destanmc.com:25565 HTTP/1.1" 302 210
34.91.147.149 - - [28/May/2021:10:35:08 +0000] "CONNECT play.destanmc.com:25565 HTTP/1.1" 302 210
34.91.147.149 - - [28/May/2021:10:35:16 +0000] "CONNECT play.destanmc.com:25565 HTTP/1.1" 302 210
34.91.147.149 - - [28/May/2021:10:35:46 +0000] "CONNECT play.destanmc.com:25565 HTTP/1.1" 302 210
194.93.56.130 - - [28/May/2021:16:40:12 +0000] "CONNECT 45.131.0.108:25565 HTTP/1.1" 404 13899
194.93.56.130 - - [28/May/2021:16:40:32 +0000] "CONNECT 45.131.108.30:25565 HTTP/1.1" 404 13920
194.163.135.185 - - [28/May/2021:17:52:52 +0000] "CONNECT play.arkflame.com:25566 HTTP/1.1\n" 400 226
194.163.135.185 - - [28/May/2021:17:52:52 +0000] "CONNECT play.arkflame.com:25566 HTTP/1.1\n" 400 226
212.47.244.68 - - [28/May/2021:20:14:24 +0000] "CONNECT www.mypersonaldomain.com:443 HTTP/1.1" 302 212
212.47.244.68 - - [28/May/2021:20:14:24 +0000] "CONNECT www.mypersonaldomain.com:443 HTTP/1.1" 302 212
212.47.244.68 - - [28/May/2021:20:14:24 +0000] "CONNECT www.mypersonaldomain.com:443 HTTP/1.1" 302 212
212.47.244.68 - - [28/May/2021:20:14:24 +0000] "CONNECT www.mypersonaldomain.com:443 HTTP/1.1" 302 212
212.47.244.68 - - [28/May/2021:20:14:24 +0000] "CONNECT www.mypersonaldomain.com:443 HTTP/1.1" 302 212
212.47.244.68 - - [28/May/2021:20:14:24 +0000] "CONNECT www.mypersonaldomain.com:443 HTTP/1.1" 302 212
```

The server is built on an AWS Lightsail instance using a Bitnami WordPress stack where the recommended, and the default, configuration is to configure Apache to serve static files (images, CSS, JavaScript and more) and use PHP_FPM with Apache’s **mod_proxy** module to handle PHP requests.

1. Does those log entries about the requests with 302 response mean that my server is used as
   an open proxy?
2. Why someone would ask my server to CONNECT that way
   to my domain?
3. Is there something can I do in order to block
   redirections and secure my server without to disable mod_proxy?
4. How could I send CONNECT requests by myself for testing?

Comment: someone is trying to use your server as a proxy, does not mean it is working. Unless you have "ProxyRequests on" and mod_proxy_connect module loaded those attempts will do nothing.

Comment: mod_proxy_connect module is loaded but ProxyRequests is not turned on. So, even if it's not working as a proxy, the server takes the trouble to check the resources so to inform  the requestor with http responses (400, 404, 302) . Is this a proper behavior?

Comment: I comment out every module I do not specifically require.  And if you have no need for CONNECT, you could block these requests.